# Select statement unable to find argument name misspelled

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table sec1202 has four columns: row_id, col_1, col_2, and col_3.

I have been given this task:

> Write a select statement that groups the rows by the value in col_1 and for each group determines the sum of the values in col_3.

Here is a screen shot of the SEC1202 table

[image]

Here is my code:

```
select col_1, count(col_3) as column_three_values,
from sec1202
group by col_3;
```

Here is the error:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by the wrong column and you want `sum()`:

```
select col_1, sum(col_3) as column_three_values
from sec1202
group by col_1;
-------------^
```

The keys in the `group by` clause generally do not appear as arguments to aggregation functions, such as `sum()` or `count()`.  The *unaggregated* columns in the `select` are generally the keys.

You also used `count()` rather than `sum()`, even though the question specifically asks for a sum.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors:

- you have a stray `,` before your `FROM` statement,
- you are using `COUNT` when you need `SUM`, and
- you are grouping by `col_3` when you are supposed to group by `col_1`.

The first is what is causing the error you are seeing. The others just mean that your results will be incorrect.

The correct SQL would be:

```
SELECT col_1,
    SUM(col_3) AS column_three_values
FROM sec1202
GROUP BY col_1;
```

Note that it is conventional to capitalize reserved words and built-in function names, such as `SELECT`, `SUM`, `FROM`, etc., for readability and clarity.